# Encounter "operation not permitted" error when using find even though terminal has been granted full disk access

Tags: macos, terminal, macbook-pro

I tried to use find command to find a file named color.cfg (It is a configuration file for latex)
Here is my code:

```
Yichens-MacBook-Pro:~ apple$ sudo find / -name "color.cfg"
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-dvisvgm/en/color.cfg
find: /Library/Caches/com.apple.aned: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Library/Templates/Data/private/var/db/oah: Operation not permitted
/System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/color.cfg
/System/Volumes/Data/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/doc/generic/pgf/version-for-dvisvgm/en/color.cfg
find: /System/Volumes/Data/.Spotlight-V100: No such file or directory
find: /System/Volumes/Data/net: No such file or directory
find: /System/Volumes/Data/boot: No such file or directory
find: /System/Volumes/Data/.PKInstallSandboxManager-SystemSoftware: No such file or directory
find: /System/Volumes/Data/.adobeTemp: No such file or directory
find: /System/Volumes/Data/Network: No such file or directory
find: /System/Volumes/Data/Library/Caches/com.apple.aned: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/System/Library/Templates/Data/private/var/db/oah: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/mnt: No such file or directory
find: /System/Volumes/Data/.fseventsd: No such file or directory
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/networkd/db: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/appinstalld: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/fpsd/dvp: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/installcoordinationd: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/oah: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/lockdown: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/KernelExtensionManagement/Staging: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/DifferentialPrivacy: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/MobileIdentityService: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/searchparty: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/CoreDuet/Knowledge: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/db/ConfigurationProfiles/Store: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/0/SafariFamily: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/0/com.apple.ScreenTimeAgent/Store: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/0/com.apple.lockoutagent: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/0/com.apple.progressd/ClassKit: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/0/com.apple.exchangesync: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/0/com.apple.Safari/SafariFamily: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/0/dmd: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/0/com.apple.nsurlsessiond: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/0/com.apple.SharedWebCredentials: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/0/com.apple.routined: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/C/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.Sandbox: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/C/com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/C/com.apple.WebKit.Networking.Sandbox: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/C/com.apple.quicklook.ThumbnailsAgent/com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/C/com.apple.WebKit.GPU.Sandbox: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000sm00006d/0: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000sm00006d/C: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000y800007k/0/com.apple.nsurlsessiond: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000z000007r/0/com.apple.nsurlsessiond: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000z000007r/0/com.apple.routined: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/protected/trustd/private: Operation not permitted
find: /System/Volumes/Data/.DocumentRevisions-V100: No such file or directory
find: /System/Volumes/Data/dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /System/Volumes/Data/dev/fd/4: Not a directory
find: /System/Volumes/Data/dev/fd/6: Not a directory
find: /System/Volumes/Data/.PreviousSystemInformation: No such file or directory
find: /System/Volumes/Data/.TemporaryItems: No such file or directory
find: /System/Volumes/iSCPreboot: No such file or directory
find: /System/DriverKit: No such file or directory
find: /private/var/networkd/db: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/db/appinstalld: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/db/fpsd/dvp: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/db/installcoordinationd: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/db/oah: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/db/lockdown: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/db/KernelExtensionManagement/Staging: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/db/DifferentialPrivacy: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/db/MobileIdentityService: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/db/searchparty: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/db/CoreDuet/Knowledge: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/db/ConfigurationProfiles/Store: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/0/SafariFamily: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/0/com.apple.ScreenTimeAgent/Store: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/0/com.apple.lockoutagent: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/0/com.apple.progressd/ClassKit: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/0/com.apple.exchangesync: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/0/com.apple.Safari/SafariFamily: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/0/dmd: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/0/com.apple.nsurlsessiond: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/0/com.apple.SharedWebCredentials: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/0/com.apple.routined: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/C/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.Sandbox: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/C/com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/C/com.apple.WebKit.Networking.Sandbox: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/C/com.apple.quicklook.ThumbnailsAgent/com.apple.QuickLook.thumbnailcache: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/ys/nkcxlbwj4qldtphp_278zpbw0000gn/C/com.apple.WebKit.GPU.Sandbox: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000sm00006d/0: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000sm00006d/C: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000y800007k/0/com.apple.nsurlsessiond: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000z000007r/0/com.apple.nsurlsessiond: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n00000z000007r/0/com.apple.routined: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/0/com.apple.LaunchServices.dv: Operation not permitted
find: /private/var/protected/trustd/private: Operation not permitted
find: /dev/fd/3: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/4: Not a directory
find: /dev/fd/6: Not a directory
```

As you can see, the screen is clustered with "operation not permitted" error and "Not a directory" error, which makes it impossible for me to search for files that I need.

[This solution doesn't work](https://osxdaily.com/2018/10/09/fix-operation-not-permitted-terminal-error-macos/) as I have already given the full disk access permission to the terminal.
[image]

Comment: I presume you are on Big Sur or newer. The boot volume is now read-only, encrypted & signed. idk where Latex now stores its files, but it shouldn't be in there.

Comment: That kinda make find command inoperative, no?

Comment: No, it doesn’t. Just don’t run it from the root folder, pick a few more specific areas to look in. I’d start with your homedir, if this is a user-specific config, or the Latex “app” (which is likely a folder, if it’s a regular macOS app).

Comment: Can you provide more detail like an `ls -la` on one of the files to better understand what MacOS thinks it is or does that fail as well?

Comment: The same, for example, if I type *ls -la /System/Volumes/Data/private/var/networkd/d
b*, the result is *ls: db: Operation not permitted*,

Comment: @jimtut But how am I to know which folder to start. I mean, if I know, I won't need to use find command in the first place.

Comment: As I said, try it from your homedir first.  Then maybe from /Applications and /usr  No need to go into /System at all, and probably not /Library.  Maybe look in /etc, but that would be weird too, as the app would need admin/sudo access to write there.  Also, maybe try a different question just asking where that file is stored, and tag the question with "latex".  You might just find that someone knows.  Or Google it.  I found tons of locations for this file on a Mac just by Googling for `mac latex "color.cfg"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directories look system related so it is expected that your user would not have permissions to read the content. Giving your terminal emulator full disk access will not change that, that would be a massive security risk.

There is another solution which works on every unix based and most other OS:

##### redirect error output

Usually on unixoidal operating systems you can redirect [stderr](https://www.computerhope.com/jargon/s/stderr.htm) to a file so that it wont clutter your terminals stdout by adding `2> /somefile`.

**Example:**

`sudo find / -name "color.cfg" 2> /dev/null`

Comment: Just checks it, works great!